# What is 漕ぎに来てくれるフラグ in English?

Tags: translation

これは漕ぎに来てくれるフラグ?

I read that on twitter. This is the tweet, if it helps to make sense of it.

自信…なくないです( ´ ▽ ` )ﾉ笑RT @yamadamic: あらマオにゃん!これは漕ぎに来てくれるフラグ?（笑） RT @mao_sid: 出勤時に聴いてましたよ（＾∇＾）RT @mizuuchitakeshi: 楽しかった(^O^)やまちゃんありがとう～汗だくだ…

All that I understand is that it says, "Is this ***_*__*_*__**?"

Comment: Maybe yamadamic's previous tweet may prove useful.

Comment: Should we really be treating this site as a translation service?

Comment: The problem is that the examples are so peculiar and the word in question does not have much wide usage.

Comment: I doubt that this will ever be useful in the future. Probably one of the [many](http://loco.yahoo.co.jp/qa/1266953682/) [other](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1266953682) [places](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1066949255) you [posted](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1066957870) this question would be more suitable for this type of question.

Comment: I didn't post it in that first place. I don't know how that got there?

Comment: @rintaun What is the reason that you claim those posts are language hacker's? I believe only langauge hacker knows whether they are his/hers.

Comment: @sawa [The profile of the user that posted those questions](http://my.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/my/k1llphil) lists the [a youtube profile](http://www.youtube.com/user/nextgenvisualkei) that publicly posted the video originally linked to in [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1963/384). Also, he has also cross-posted many of the [other](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1266598912) [questions](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1166962871) he's asked on this site. As far as I'm concerned, "I didn't post that" is just a blatant lie.

Comment: @sawa That said, the cross-posting is not itself a problem, as far as I'm concerned -- though it may be a little bit inconsiderate to those answering the questions.

Comment: No, I am not a liar. Some of those were cross-posted. I am saying that the first one was one that I did not post. http://loco.yahoo.co.jp/qa/1266953682/ I don't know how that got there. That is a copy of something I posted somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`フラグ` started to be used recently as an internet slang. It means an 'advance hint', 'indication of something that will happen later', or 'some fact that will make much sense when some other fact is revealed later'. It is woven into the context intentionally (as in detective stories) or it happens non-intentionally. A normal way of saying it is `伏線`.

It comes from the English 'flag', whose relevant usage is, according to my speculation, a global boolean variable used in computer programming to keep the state of something and is used later.

Comment: Yeah, like when watching a horror movie, if the door behind a character opens slowly and a figure shows up carrying a chainsaw, people would say 死亡フラグ or フラグが立った