# What does 理由の回収 mean? Is this a set expression or phrase or what?

Tags: grammar, meaning

A live-stream gamer on YouTube wrote this sentence on his video description that normally goes beneath the video when you click 'Show more...' .

> ロックマン10をクリアしたのですが、9の時にワイリー土下座が9回あった理由の回収です。

Google translate:

> I cleared Rockman 10. It is the recovery of the reason why Wily Dogeza was 9 times at 9.

I think he is trying to say, "I've already beaten MegaMan 10, but I'm gonna re-discover the reason as to why Wily was defeated 9 times so far in this 9th MegaMan game."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

回収 in a context like this refers to [payoff](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Setup_and_payoff), the act of giving an answer to a previous foreshadowing/mystery. 伏線を回収する is a common set phrase meaning "to pay off the foreshadowing". [フラグ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2061/5010)を回収する is also common. 理由を回収する is not really a common set phrase, but can be understood in the same manner.

- 9の時にワイリー土下座が9回あった理由
  the reason why Wily's *dogeza* appeared 9 times in Mega Man 9
- ～の回収です。
  This is the payoff (part) about ～.
  This (scene/video) finally explains ～.

Answer (score 1):

> ((9の時にワイリー土下座が9回あった)理由の)回収です。

It seems to me your question is about the relative clause inside that sentence which may have clouded your understanding of the sentence. I hope partitioning the sentence this way helps clears it up for you.

- 9の時にワイリー土下座が9回あった modifies 理由, and tells us what that reason is, namely answers the why question
- 9の時にワイリー土下座が9回あった理由 modifies 回収 and tells us the whole reason is a reason for the 回収

You can also use ため here to explain the reason: 9の時にワイリー土下座が9回あったための回収

Without more context it's hard for me to tell what 回収 here means. I'm also not sure why [dogeza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogeza) is mentioned.

Comment: In general, I can't think of a case where 〜理由のＸ means the reason described is one for Ｘ when the preceding clause already answers the why question. You would say 〜こと／のが理由のＸ in that case.

Comment: in any Megaman game, when you defeat the evil scientist - Dr.Willy, there will be a scene showing Willy knelt down before Megaman/ Rockman and bow to him (in dogeza  style of JP) >> like asking for Megaman/Rockman's forgiveness and spare his life

Comment: @aguijonazo Okay I see! I think there's a fine distinction here that I need to get a better handle on.